# Resample dates from a CSV file using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that has a column like the following:

```
            DateTime  Global_active_power  ...  Sub_metering_2  Sub_metering_3
0     2007-02-01 00:00:00                0.442  ...               0               0
1     2007-02-01 00:01:00                0.370  ...               0               0
2     2007-02-01 00:02:00                0.368  ...               0               0
3     2007-02-01 00:03:00                0.370  ...               0               0
4     2007-02-01 00:04:00                0.370  ...               0               0
```

I am trying to group that table in 15 minute intervals, for this I was using this code:

```
 DF = pd.read_csv('power_consumption.csv')
 df = pd.DataFrame(DF)
 intervalo = df.resample('W')
 print(intervalo)
```

But I get the following error: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

What would be a better way to do it?
Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: assuming DateTime column is of dtype datetime try `intervalo =df.set_index('Datetime').resample('15 min')`

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.